# How to make an option preselected in dropdown - activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

```
f.input :country_id, :prompt => 'Select Country', :as => :select, :collection => Country.all.map{|m| [m.name, m.id]} }
```

How to make one of the options from dropdown to be preselected. For example to select the value with id 5 what should be done?

Comment: remove `prompt`  and give it a try

Comment: but how to try?

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
f.input :country_id, label: 'country', :as => :select, :collection => Country.all.map{|m| [m.name, m.id]},include_blank: false
```

just include 'include_blank:' parameter

Hope its work

Comment: It works if I want to make first option selected. What if I want to make other option selected?

Comment: try :selected => option